# RavenDB Trigger for updated index

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to use something like a Raven Listener to detect when an index has changed. When a document is inserted to the database, I want to be able to wait until the index is refreshed before the trigger is fired. Does anyone have any ideas?

I saw Ayende's post on using the subscribe method:

```
store.Changes()
      .DocumentSubscription("orders/1293")
      .Subscribe(Reload);
```

but couldn't find any more details on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Francis,
You can do this using:

```
store.Changes().ForIndex("YourIndex").Subscribe(DoSomething);
```